# How to override the last line break on batch file?

Tags: batch-file

#### How to override the last line break on batch file?

I am doing this:

```
call xcopy /E /S /Y "%FILE_PATH%" "%DEST%"|find /v "%FILE_NAME%"
call echo , to the folder %folder%"
```

And it is outputting this:

```
1 File(s) copied
, to the folder F:\SteamCMD\steamapps\common
```

But I want to output like this:

```
1 File(s) copied, to the folder F:\SteamCMD\steamapps\common
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /E /S /Y "%FILE_PATH%" "%DEST%"^|find /v "%FILE_NAME%" ') do echo %%a, to the folder %folder%
```

should work - I haven't tried it.

Use `for /f` with `"delims="` to assign the output from the `xcopy` command to `%%a` then regurgitate that line with the appendix.

Answer (score 1):

How about following script?
Result from "xcopy" is put to variable, and "nul" is inputted to standard input. Then the variable is output as standard output.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`call xcopy /E /S /Y "%FILE_PATH%" "%DEST%"^|find /v "%FILE_NAME%"`) do (
  set /p<nul=%%a || call echo , to the folder %folder%"
)
```

I'm sorry if this is wrong.

Comment: Why your is better than the other answer? Why do you use two `||` and `usebackq`? Why sorry if this is wrong? Why it would be wrong?

Comment: This looks kind of over-complicated to me; why using `set /P` and `echo` when a single `echo` was sufficient? Both `call` commands are unneeded. Using `usebackq` and back-ticks ` is the same as not using `usebackq` and apostrophies `'`, it is just a matter of taste.